# How to load HTML code into a table using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm building a simple website which consists of a header (the title and a menu) and a table, in which the content is placed (because then I can make the layout easier). The problem is that each time I change the category (click a link in the menu), the whole site becomes white for a short period of time, while it's loading. I'd like it so this doesn't happen, so I only need to load the content of the table, not the whole page. I guess this could easily be done using frames, but I was told that they will stop being supported soon, and that it's a bad practice using them. Is there a way to do this?

For the time being, the site is here, so you can see the effect I'm talking about: <del>http://bljak.org:1235/index.html</del>.

Also, it would be the best if site was just HTML and Javascript, because I'm not really familiar with PHP (and I'm coding on a netbook with 512Mb of RAM, so I doubt I could start a server there).

Comment: did not know people still made websites this way except for maybe the tor browser !!!  but you can do a jQuery.Ajax({}); but this maybe a little over your head

Comment: Is there anything bad in making a website this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give way based on jQuery - this is the most simple and short way.

First, download the latest jQuery library - can be found [here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js).

Suppose you name your local file "jquery.min.js" have such line in your existing HTML code to "include" the jQuery library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now all you need is this code in your page and you're done:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").bind("click", function() {
            var href = $(this).attr("href");

            //bust nasty browser AJAX cache:
            href += "?nnn=" + parseInt(Math.random() * 1000000);

            $("#Container").load(href);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Replace the **Container** with the ID of the actual element in your page that should contain the "body" then clicking any link will cause the linked page to be loaded into the container without full page reload.

The code is pretty much straightforward, feel free to ask if you want to understand any part of it though.

jQuery is less than 100K so with modern internet speed it really shouldn't be any problem - pure JavaScript is of course possible, but will cause lots of headache in keeping it cross browser.

Comment: But, there seem to be errors: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/user/Desktop/Latinski/izgovorigs.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. What should I do and what does this mean?

Comment: @bane - You should be running this under some sort of server - when you upload to your real domain it would work. To be able to test locally I fear you'll have to install web server.

Comment: If you have Windows, you can install [IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1038) it looks pretty basic and will be enough for your needs.

Comment: I've installed IIS Express as you recommended. I'm a little bit confused though, how do I "link" it to my site? Also, does it have a UI, or is it an exclusively console application? I really don't like it when a program doesn't put a shortcut to my desktop and simply closes after it's finished installing...

Comment: @bane [this](http://code.manikkothu.com/blogs/iisexpress-configurelocalwebsite) looks like a great article, let me know if you'll still have problems after reading it. :)

Comment: I actually figured it out myself now, but I'll give it a look!

Comment: Hey, now I have another problem... The sites don't update! The only update when I load them as separate pages...

Comment: @bane not sure what you mean.. what you mean by "sites don't update"?

Comment: When I change something in the HTML file, and load it into a table using the .load() method, the changes aren't displayed.

Comment: @bane - yeah, nasty IE cache.. see my edited code for a workaround. :)

Comment: @bane guess it was infectious then, lol.. doesn't matter - the added line should bust any such cache by adding random element to the URL. :)

Comment: Very strange, it works locally, but when I put it on my friends' server, it doesn't... 404, bla?|random_number|, the error message went something like that.

Comment: Any idea as to why this happens?

Comment: @bane what server is it? What is the page URL? Did you try without the random cache buster?

Comment: I switched to developing solely on Linux. Everything seems to work here... Even when I load the page on a Windows machine. So yeah, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use innerHTML to rewrite the text between the tag and its close tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText(){
    document.getElementById('tbl').innerHTML = '<table><tr><td>New Text</td></tr></table>';
}
</script>
<div id="tbl"></div> 
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:changeText()" value="Change Text"/>
```

Comment: Yes, of course. But, that would mean I would need to copy an entire HTML page (or just a table) into that single statement, and making changes would be a bit painful... I was looking for something like that, but without directly putting the code in. Also, when I try to copy that table into the quotes, it kinda breaks somewhere (the quotation)...